# Method won't run because it returns no string

Tags: java

I'm creating a battleship game where a ship occupies 3 cells and you have to guess which cell. Once they guess it you return "hit" and if not you return "miss". Once they hit all 3 you return "kill". I've written the code but it states I still haven't returned a string.

```
public class SimpleBattleShip{
int[] shipCoordinates;
int numOfHits;

String updateStatus(int guess){
    for(int i=0;i<shipCoordinates.length;i++){
        if(guess == shipCoordinates[i]){
            numOfHits++;
            if(numOfHits ==3){
                return "kill";
            }else{
                return "hit";
            }
        }else{
            return "miss";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The way you've written this, you'll only ever iterate the `for` loop once.  The `return "miss";` needs to be at the bottom, outside of the loop, so that the program has the chance to check more of the coordinates than just the first one.

Comment: If `shipCoordinates.length` was 0 then nothing in the `for` loop would be run, and execution would reach the end of the method without ever returning anything. You must add code to deal with that case. You must satisfy the compiler that something is always returned.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just separating the NumberofHits If statement from the for loop. The problem may be the for loop iterating the whole 'hit check' for each value of 'i' which may cause it to put up false values before tallying the full amount of hits.

I've tried throwing in an else if to maybe tighten the parameters. turn it back to else if you want (this is for hit & miss).

```
public class SimpleBattleShip {
    int[] shipCoordinates;
    int numOfHits;

    String updateStatus(int guess) {
        for (int i = 0; i < shipCoordinates.length; i++) {
            if (guess == shipCoordinates[i]) {
                numOfHits++;
            }
        }
            
        if (numOfHits == 3) {
            return "kill";
        } else if (numOfHits < 3 && numOfHits >= 1) {
            return "hit";
        } else {
             return "miss";
        }
    }
}
```